# How to ignore the first two characters of a String

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to get only what is after the /n and subsequent spances in the following string, how do I do it?

This is the string:

```
"\n                Crimes de Calúnia, Injúria e Difamação de Competência do Juiz Singular "
```

I need to get only whats after the spaces, how can I do it?

Comment: You could `.trim()` the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.trimStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimStart)

```js
let input = "\n                Crimes de Calúnia, Injúria e Difamação de Competência do Juiz Singular ";

let result = input.trimStart();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `trimLeft` does not take any parameters. Also, the preferred version is `trimStart`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte thank you, modified my answer

Comment: It worked just fine. Thanks